# Função Porcentagem em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Como fazer uma função de porcentagem. No qual ele calcule a `td` ou seja a tabela igual do Excel para dar a porcentagem.

Quero calcular a porcentagem de um valor em PHP, por exemplo 10% de 100, tipo o Excel `DADOSx100=%` e calcular as tabelas em PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$valor = 100; // valor total
$porcent = 50;
$totalporcent = 100;
$total = $porcent / $totalporcent;

$resultado = $total * $valor;

echo $porcent . "% de " . $totalporcent ." é: " .
$resultado;

//é igual ao de cima, mas achei melhor explicar um pouco melhor kkk
```

Answer (score 6):

Considerando o que você falou no comentário da sua pergunta ficaria assim:

```
$valor = 100; // valor total
$porcent = 10 / 100; // 10%

$resultado = $porcent * $valor;

echo "10% de 100 é: " .
$resultado;
```

Comment: Obrigado Amigo *(Ajudou Muito).

Comment: Ricardo, dá um confere neste faq: [JS, CSS e HTML executáveis no corpo da pergunta ou resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/201)